# To display a messagebox with hyperlink using win32api and python?

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32

My code is like this:

```
import win32api
message = "[![Go to http://www.google.com][1]][1]"
win32api.MessageBox(0, 'Message', 'title')
```

It displays a MessageBox with the message, but what I want is the href can be a hyperlink which user could click.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: `TaskDialogIndirect()` might be able to do what you want with some combination of settings. No idea how to use it from Python; sorry. Also note that it requires Vista and Common Controls 6.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you, but simple MessageBox can not do this. You can try with the suggestion user *andlabs* said, or make your own dialog box template in resource editor and then code it to behave like the message box with the link. :((